# ECHO is off error when printing line to a file

Tags: batch-file

```
SET NEWLINE=^& echo.

FIND /C /I "telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts > NUL 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^0.0.0.0 telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

New to batch scripting. I seem to be getting and ECHO is off error which seems to have something to do with a variable not being set? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the nonhacky method of outputting a newline via `echo.`:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo.&echo 0.0.0.0 telemetry.microsoft.com)>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

#### Explanation of the problem:

After expansion the first echo (that is inside `newline` variable) doesn't have anything to output and thus it displays its status.

1. `.` should be at the beginning so that it's appended to the first `echo` to actually output the newline
2. No space needed between `echo` and `%newline%` so that the added dot follows `echo`
3. `^` between `%newline%` and the following text is not needed as there's nothing to *escape*
4. Both `echo` commands should be surrounded with `(` `)` to indicate output redirection scope

So your original code might be like this:

```
    SET NEWLINE=.^& echo

    FIND /C /I "telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts > NUL 2>&1
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (ECHO%NEWLINE% 0.0.0.0 telemetry.microsoft.com)>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```